# Finding an index in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

What I'm trying to achieve is to return a certain track when a corresponding index is equal to the track number.

```
private ArrayList<Track> tracksN;

public Track getTrack(int index)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tracksN.size(); i++)
    {
        if (tracksN.size().get(i)==index)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I'm getting error message: int cannot be dereferenced.

Comment: How can you use a double equal operator on primitive and an object? This is a disastrous compilation error.

Comment: You call `tracksN.size()` which returns an `int`.  This is causing the compile time error (you can't call a method on an `int`).  What you likely want is `tracksN.get(i).getTrack()`--or whatever method from the class `Track` returns its integer track value.

Comment: Why don't you need a separate method to get object from `ArrayList` by index. There's already `get(int index)` in `ArrayList`.

Comment: @WundwinBorn It seems pretty obvious to me that the input `index` is _not_ the index into the `ArrayList` rather the value of the track held in the `Track` object which is held in the `ArrayList`.  Without some kind of sorting, you need to search the entire `ArrayList` to find the desired track (which presumably can be stored in any order).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you iterate (when you need the `i`th track). You can just do:

```
public Track getTrack(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < tracksN.size()) {
       return tracksN.get(index); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `I don't understand why you iterate` the whole code has no logic so... not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
if (tracksN.size().get(i)==index)
```

It should be

```
 if (tracksN.get(i)==index)
```

`tracksN` is an `ArrayList` there is no such method `.size().get(i)`. `tracksN.get(i)` will return the `Track` you should able to get the field from it to compare.

Also take a look at your method.

```
public Track getTrack(int index){ // you should return a Track not int

}
```

You have to correct all those issue.

You can get the Track by index easily using `get(index)`

Read about [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) in `Java`

Comment: I tried it that way and I got Incomparable types: Track and int

Comment: @Downvoter should have the courage to put a comment at least.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you before I did, but your answer is completely incomplete.  It's pretty clear what he is trying to do and you did not even come close to addressing that.

Comment: @Jared stackOverFlow not provide code in full. But will help OP to think again by explaining things.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera 1) you provided incorrect code: `if(tracksN.get(i) == index)` <-- this is not compilable code and 2) your only other contribution was to point out the obvious: that his method should return a `Track` object, not an `int`.  Then you referenced [List.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) without explanation which is not helpful to a novice programmer and is redundant when you already stated that the the method should return a `Track` object while the OP is trying to return an `int` (but you don't state explicitly this fact).

Answer (score 0):

Look, I'm assuming you have a class `Track` with an integer value `track`, such as the following:

```
public class Track{
    public final int track;

    public Track(final int track){
        this.track = track;
    }

    public int getTrack(){
        // this method is unnecessary if you declare
        //    track as public final
        return track;
    }
}
```

So now your method should search your `ArrayList` of `Track` objects for the intended index:

```
public Track getTrack(final int track){
    for(final Track thisTrack: tracks){
        if(thisTrack.getTrack() == track)
            return thisTrack;
    }
    // the track wasn't found, return null
    return null;
}
```

All of this assumes that the track index is unique--otherwise you will return the first `Track` object that you put into the `ArrayList` that matches your search criterion.

...better yet, if you use the `public final` designation for the variable `track`, then you can simply do:

```
public Track getTrack(final int track){
    for(final Track thisTrack: tracks){
        if(thisTrack.track == track)
            return thisTrack;
    }
    // the track wasn't found, return null
    return null;
}
```

If you want to recycle your `Track` objects, then the internal varibale `int track` should be private and you should provide getter and setter methods, but if you think once a `Track` object is created it will never be changed (i.e. is immutable), then you should go with the `public final int track` declaration so that accessing the variable (which never changes and is a primitive) doesn't require a method call.

There is even another option you can go with, which I highly discourage, but you can overwrite the `equals` method in `Object` and use the `indexOf` method in `ArrayList` to find your object:

```
public class Track{
    public final int track;

    public Track(final int track){
        this.track = track;
    }

    public int getTrack(){
        // this method is unnecessary if you declare
        //    track as public final
        return track;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o){
        // make sure this object is a Track object
        if(o instanceof Track){
            final Track t = (Track)o;
            // if the two track indices equal each other then they are
            //   same track object
            return t.track == track;
        }
        // this Object isn't a Track object and so definitely isn't equal to 
        //   this Track object
        return false;
}
```

Then in your search you can create a new `Track` object (this is bad because it adds unnecessary memory to the heap which will need to be garbage collected later--primitives are added to the stack which is why the above is preferred--things added to the stack are immediately reclaimed once the method returns):

```
public Track getTrack(final int track){
    // create a new Track object to search for
    final Track testTrack = new Track(track);
    // get the index of this Track object (if isn't in the list, this will 
    //    return -1)
    final int index = tracks.indexOf(testTrack);

    // if index is valid return the track at the given index, else
    //   return null (the Track doesn't exist).
    return index >= 0 ? tracks.get(index) : null;
}
```

Comment: stackOverFlow not provide code in full. But will help OP to think again by explaining things.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera OK, first off, if you want to flag this as a bad question go for it (it probably is).  Second, your answer still does not help the OP at all.  I provided a comment on the question which explained the compile time error and you challenged me to provide a solution--which I did.  Furthermore, I went into detail to help the OP write good Java code (via public vs. private vs. method declarations) so in my opinion, I'm helping the OP to become a better programmer.

Answer (score -1):

look! you declare a method as:

```
public Track getTrack(int index)
{
/*..*/
}
```

so the return value must be an instance of Track or null value. But here in the loop you return an int value. that's why!

Comment: What's funny is that each answer points out a different huge mistake in this code.

Comment: yup! a basic mistake! @Dici